# How much time is too much?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

Given that the standard number of ticks for a cycle in a WP7 app is 333,333 ticks (or it is if you set it as such), how much of this time slice does someone have to work in?

To put it another way, how many ticks do the standard processes eat up (Drawing the screen, clearing buffers, etc)?

I worked out a process for doing something in a Spike (as I often do) but it is eating up about (14 ms) of time right now (about half the time slice that I have available) and I am concerned about what will happen if it runs past that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conventional way of doing computationally intensive things is to do them on a background thread - this means that the UI thread(s) don't block while the computations are occurring - typically the UI threads are scheduled ahead of the background threads so that the screen drawing continues smoothly even though the CPU is 100% busy. This approach allows you to queue as much work as you want to.

If you need to do the computational work within the UI thread - e.g. because its part of game mechanics or part of the "per frame" update/drawing logic, then conventionally what happens is that the game frame rate slows down a bit because the phone is waiting on your logic before it can draw.

If your question is "what is a decent frame rate?" Then that depends a bit on the type of app/game, but generally (at my age...) I think anything 30Hz and above is OK - so up to 33ms for each frame - and it is important that the frame rate is smooth - i.e. each frame length takes about the same time.

I hope that approximately answers your question... wasn't entirely sure I understood it!

Comment: The process I am performing is pixel parsing to determine collisions and bounce vector (normal) so, unfortunately, it does need to be in the main thread. I am using bounding boxes to limit when the checks are performed and the truely intensive stuff only happens when a collision actually occurs. Just wondering if 14ms would cause less than smooth gameplay during those moments when it happens.

Comment: I think the best answer for you is to "suck it and see". To be honest, 14ms sounds doable - that does start you at a basic 60Hz...  Once you've got some code running, you'll need to test on a real phone - emulator no good for you. Alternatively you could easily take a standard sample XNA app and add a 14ms busy loop to the game loop to see what the effect is.

Comment: Yea I am pushing forward. I have actually tested the app on a phone before this point just don't have one at the moment. I marked your response as the answer because I appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: I guessed you had to have had access to a phone - otherwise measuring 14ms would be "tricky"! Good luck!